# Area of 2-dimensional convex hull of 4 points?

Tags: analytic-geometry, area, convex-hulls

Let $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ be four 2-dimensional points (in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is), with coordinates $x_i,y_i$. Is there a formula for the area of their [convex-hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?

Comment: I think first you have to find the ordering of vertices on the convex hull boundary, and then you can apply the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid).

Comment: @Rahul How can I compute the ordering?

Comment: There are lots of [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), the simplest ones being [gift wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) and [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan).